# Vocabulaire du « punting »

Tags: traduction, anglais, sport

À Oxford et Cambridge, nous avons une activité nautique qui s'appelle « *punting* ». On a un petit bateau en bois, une longue perche avec laquelle on pousse sur le fond du cours d'eau, et on fait une promenade relaxante sur la rivière.

Voici une photo pour montrer à quoi ça ressemble:

[image: Punting]

Je voudrais trouver des mots français pour le bateau, la perche et l'activité, pour l'expliquer à mes amis français.

Je n'ai pas pu les trouver dans un dictionnaire, mais j'espère qu'il y a une activité similaire en France pour donner une traduction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Il n'y a pas de traduction directe : les guides français de Cambridge parlent de *punting* sans le traduire, décrivent les embarcations comme des « bâteaux à perche » ou « bâteaux manœuvrés avec une perche ».

Il existe cependant des mots spécifiques à chaque région pour désigner ce genre d'embarcation et son mode de propulsion :

- La perche elle-même s'appelle une *bourde* sur la Loire, une *bergade* dans le sud-ouest de la France, une *perche* (ou une *[pigouille](http://projetbabel.org/fluvial/yole.htm)*) dans le marais poitevin, etc.
- Le bateau est une *[plate](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plate_%28bateau%29)* (non spécifique à une région en particulier, et qui s'applique aussi à des embarcations plus grosses), une *yole*, une *piate*, un *batai* (marais poitevin), un *[chaland](http://projetbabel.org/fluvial/chaland_briere.htm)* (marais de Brière), etc.
- L'action a moins de noms, à ma connaissance : [*bouter*](http://projetbabel.org/fluvial/b.htm) est le seul verbe que je connaisse.

D'une manière générale, le [lexique fluvial et batelier](http://projetbabel.org/fluvial/lexique.htm) est un bon point de départ pour explorer ce vocabulaire !

Comment: Ce que c'est que la culture, quand même.

Answer (score 5):

On parle souvent de navigation à la perche, ou encore navigation à la bourde (la bourde étant la perche qui sert à manoeuvrer le bateau).

Globalement, l'activité rentre dans le cadre de la batellerie (et est pratiqué par des bateliers), mais je crois que la batellerie est un cadre plus large, qui comprend tous les types de navigation sur des rivières.

Answer (score 4):

Dans la pratique je pense que ce genre d'embarcation sera surtout qualifié par une périphrase du genre "barque à fond plat propulsée à la perche".

Comment: +1 pour la réponse des gens normalement incultes ^_^'

Answer (score 3):

Cette barque m'a l'air d'être une [plate](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/plate).

[Batellerie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/batellerie) pour moi concerne le transport de marchandise par bateau et ne recouvre pas les activités de plaisance comme celle-là.

Je ne vois pas de nom particulier pour cette activité nautique.